# how to display information texts when dialog open

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, frontend

I have this help dialog and some reason my information texts are not showing as soon as the dialog is open. It only start to show when I click the subsection so just wonder how I can display it as soon as the user open the dialog box. Any suggestion or help will be really appreciated.

HTML

```
//Clicking this will take the user each subsection

<div *ngFor="let subSection of mappedSecSub | async; let last=last">
  <div *ngIf="subSection.parentId == section.id;" (click)="clicked(subSection.id, section.id)">
   <a mat-list-item>{{subSection.name}}
   <mat-divider *ngIf="!last" class="solid"></mat-divider>
   </a>
 </div>
</div>

// This display the informations text

<div class="column right">
   <div *ngFor="let section of targetSectionGroup">
   <h1 *ngIf="section.parentId == null" class="hint">{{section?.name}}</h1>
  </div>
     <div *ngFor="let section of targetSectionGroup">
     <div *ngIf="section.parentId != null">
     <h2 id="s{{section.id}}ss{{section.parentId}}"  class="hint">{{section?.name}}</h2>
    <p class="multi_lines_text" [innerHTML]="section?.text"></p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS

```
  mappedSections: BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);
  mappedSecSub = this.mappedSections.asObservable()
  targetSection: { id, name, parentId, text };
  targetSectionGroup: { id, name, parentId, text }[] = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fetchData();
  }

fetchData = () => {
    this.HelpService.getHelp().subscribe(res => {
      this.mappedSections.next(res['res'])
      let newMappedSection = this.mappedSections.getValue()
      for (let i = 0; i < newMappedSection.length; i++) {
        const element = newMappedSection[i];
        if (element.parentId) {
          this.targetSection = element;
          break
        }
      }
    })
  }

  clicked(id, parentId) {
    this.targetSectionGroup = [];
    let data = this.mappedSections.getValue()
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i].parentId == parentId || data[i].id == parentId) {
        this.targetSectionGroup.push(data[i]);
      }
      if (data[i].id === id) {
        this.targetSection = data[i]
      }
    }
    document.querySelector(`#s${id}ss${parentId}`).scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
  }
```

Right now the information text only show up when I click the subsections. I want to show it as soon as the help dialog is open.

[image]

Comment: I guess you are not initialising `targetSectionGroup` once you get response from `this.HelpService.getHelp()`. Better call the `clicked()` function there with first response data.

Comment: @PankajPrakash Hi...can you please show me how. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should work

```
fetchData = () => {
  this.HelpService.getHelp().subscribe(res => {
    this.mappedSections.next(res['res']);

    const response = res['res'];
    this.clicked(response.id, response.parentId);
    let newMappedSection = this.mappedSections.getValue()
    for (let i = 0; i < newMappedSection.length; i++) {
      const element = newMappedSection[i];
      if (element.parentId) {
        this.targetSection = element;
        break
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: not sure why it showing me only just the section name, example "Workspace" and that's it. It's not showing the subsection name and all the texts. Any idea why it not showing?. thanks

Comment: Can you share your response structure?